# About UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm learning iOS development and I'm looking at `UIGestureRecognizer`'s.

I have a view. When you tap that view, I want to show a `UIPopoverController` and I also want it to act like a `UIButton` in that it "highlights" when you press it.

The way I thought to do this was to use 2 `UIGestureRecognizer`'s - a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

The problem I'm running into is the highlight method gets called immediately (which I want) but if I then move my finger far enough, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` gets cancelled. At that point, I want to call another method (`unhighlight`) to restore the `UIView`'s initial background color, but I'm lost on how to do this.

I'm quite new to this, so this question is probably basic, and I appreciate any help that anybody can give me.

In the `UIViewController`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(togglePopover)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *press = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(highlight)];
press.minimumPressDuration = 0.f; //highlight immediately
press.delegate = self; //set the delegate to self
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:highlight];


//the delegate part of the UIViewController
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithOtherGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer {
  return YES; //allows allow simultaneous recognition of gestures on this view
}
```

Comment: If you want the view to act like a button, then why not use a `UIButton`?

Comment: Good point, and I certainly could (and probably will) - I was hoping to learn a little bit more about `UIGestureRecognizer`'s in the process of asking this question.

Comment: @rmaddy - if you make your comment a bit more answer-like and make an answer, I will accept it. You're right, I should've just used a `UIButton` - I've done so and it's working as I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the behaviour you desired is like a `UIButton`, why can't you just use a `UIButton`?

Otherwise, you have to capture the state of the gesture inside your target method. While declaring the action-target for the gesture recognizer, make sure you put a colon after the target name.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(togglePopover:)];
```

Now, inside `-togglePopover`, read the `state` property of the passed gesture recognizer. [That is documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW20). You are looking for the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`.

Answer (score 1):

A `UITapGestureRecognizer` has a given behaviour, which you have just described in your concrete case.

What you are after could be done with a continuous gesture recognizer like `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Specifically, a continuos gesture recogniser action method will receive a sequence of calls according to the states tge gesture recognizer goes thru.

One of those states is `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`, so you can manage it to detect when the gesture has been cancelled, like in your case, and act accordingly by removing the highlight. On the other hand, when your action is called in the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` state, you would highlight the button.

Your action method would be like this:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

     ...
  } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {

     ...
  }
}
```

Another approach altogether would be creating your own gesture recognizer subclass, where you would handle `touchesBegan:/touchesMoved:/touchesEnded:` methods to suit your needs.

If you give a look at the [UIGestureRecognizer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will find plenty of information.

Comment: How do you detect when a `UIGestureRecognizer` has transitioned to `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`? Seems like a basic question, but I couldn't seem to find the answer in the Apple Developer docs. Do I use KVO, maybe?

Comment: You cannot with a tap recognizer. A pan recognizer action will receive all the relevant calls because it's a continuos recogniser. See my edited answer...